# How to send named-pipe to all connected clients (Bash)

Tags: bash, named-pipes, tcpserver

I have a named pipe, to which I output log informations from several scripts. I need to make a TCP server, which sends these informations to connected clients. For one client solution, this worked fine:

```
tail -f name_of_pipe | nc -lk $tcp_port
```

Is there some effective way, how to send the content to multiple clients? I think netcat does not support multiple clients. I have found that there is utility named tcpserver from ucspi-tcp, which executes new process for each client, but this won't do what I want - Each line will be read out from named pipe and delivered just to one random client.

In fact, I don't need named pipe acting like FIFO, I can throw away everything before client has connected and send just real-time data.

Comment: What about `tee`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$ echo "Bye bye" | tee >( cat ) | tee >( cat ) | cat
Bye bye
Bye bye
Bye bye
Bye bye
```

Comment: `tee` can write to multiple files: `echo "Bye bye" | tee >( cat ) >( cat ) | cat`. (You wouldn't need the trailing `cat` if that were that were the actual process, but I assume that's a placeholder for an arbitrary consumer).